# Cómo hacer que el programa regrese a la primera pregunta?

Tags: c++

Quiero que el programa regrese a la primera pregunta pero hasta ahora solo sé como acabar el programa.

```
cout<<"bienvenido al banco \n";

system("pause");

cout<<"inserte la tarjeta\n";

system("pause");

int contraseña=1234;

cout<<"digite su contraseña\n";
cin>>contraseña;

if(contraseña!=1234)
{
    cout<<"contraseña incorecta\n";
    system("clear");
}
else
{
    cout<<"contraseña corecta\n";

    system("pause");

    cout<<"seleccione la operacion que desa realisar\n";
    cout<<"1.-transferir\n";
    cout<<"2.-retirar\n";
    cout<<"3.-estado de cuenta\n";
    cout<<"4.-salir\n";
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Iteraciones.. lee sobre eso.. y de paso, pusiste 3 lenguajes diferentes...

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Podrías hacer un diagrama de flujo de lo que quieres? O al menos decirnos desde qué punto hacia qué punto te gustaría volver? La solución más simple tal vez sea con [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) pero se desaconseja su uso y se prefiere otras alternativas.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que pretendes, pero por intuición quieres mostrar las opciones nuevamente hasta que el usuario seleccione una opción valida? Si eso es lo que deseas, tu mejor opción es un [SWITCH / CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp) . Aquí solo vas a ejecutar el bloque de código asociado a la opción que tome el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int contraseña = 1234;`introducir el código aquí`
    int opcion;

    do {
        std::cout << "Bienvenido al banco\n";
        system("pause");

        std::cout << "Inserte la tarjeta\n";
        system("pause");

        std::cout << "Digite su contraseña\n";
        int inputContraseña;
        std::cin >> inputContraseña;

        if (inputContraseña != contraseña) {
            std::cout << "Contraseña incorrecta\n";
            system("clear");
            continue; // Vuelve al inicio del bucle
        } else {
            std::cout << "Contraseña correcta\n";
            system("pause");

            std::cout << "Seleccione la operación que desea realizar\n";
            std::cout << "1.- Transferir\n";
            std::cout << "2.- Retirar\n";
            std::cout << "3.- Estado de cuenta\n";
            std::cout << "4.- Salir\n";

            std::cin >> opcion;

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    // Lógica para la operación de transferencia
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Lógica para la operación de retiro
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Lógica para la operación de estado de cuenta
                    break;
                case 4:
                    std::cout << "Saliendo del programa\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout << "Opción no válida\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while (opcion != 4); // Salir del bucle cuando la opción sea 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor explica tu respuesta. Puede que el código sirva pero si no explicas que hiciste tal vez no todos lo puedan entender.